# Mutating data in complex list

Tags: scheme, mutable

Suppose I have defined following lists:

```
(define a (list 1 2))
(define b (list a 3))
```

I defined `a` explicitly to show because I want to modify the list inside `b`. Do I need to re-construct whole data structure from scratch to add an item to inner list?

**Edit:** I'm not trying to change the element in the inner list, I want to add another element to the inner list.

Comment: note: in this particular case, you may use `set-car!` to update the _car_ field of `b` without having to reconstruct the whole data structure (r5rs).

Comment: My bad, I'm editing the question

Comment: @mtyurt it's all the same: just play with `set-car!` and `set-cdr!`, and pass as parameters the pair that you want to modify and the value, see my update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to modify the list in-place using `set-car!` and `set-cdr!`, as long as you pass as parameter the exact pair within the list that needs to be modified and the corresponding value. For example, to replace an element in the inner list:

```
(define a (list 1 2))
(define b (list a 3))

b
=> '((1 2) 3)

(set-car! (cdar b) 'x)
b
=> ((1 x) 3)
```

And if you want to add another element to the inner list, do this:

```
(set-cdr! (cdar b) '(4))
b
=> ((1 x 4) 3)
```

Comment: The problem is the technique you proposed only modifies third element of the list. How can I append new element to the list?

Comment: @mtyurt you have to find the _right pair_ that you want to modify. If it's the second pair then pass `(car b)`, if it's the third pass `(cdar b)`, for the fourth pass `(cddar b)` and so on - you get the idea, but bear in mind that you can only put so many `d`'s there, better write a helper method to find the last element in the inner list, which is the insertion point. It'll help _a lot_ if you understand how a list is built using `cons` operations

Comment: thanks. I found the right combination as follows: `(set-cdr! (list-tail (car b) (- (length (car b)) 1 )) '(7))`

Comment: @mtyurt There you go! glad to help you :)